# Compression of sorted data with small difference

Tags: compression, sorting

I have sorted data sequence of integers. Maximal difference between 2 numbers is 3. So data looks for example like this:

```
Data: 1 2 3 5 7 8 9 10 13 14
Differences: (start 1) 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 3 1
```

Is there a better way to store (compress) this type of sequences, than save difference values? Because if I use dictionary based methods, It failed to compress, because of randomness of numbers 1,2 and 3. If I use "PAQ" style compression, result are better, but still not quite satisfying. Huffman and Arithmetic coder is worse than dictionary based methods.

Is there some way with prediction?

For example to use regression for original data and than store differences (which could be smaller or more consistent)

Or use some kind of prediction based on histogram of differences?

Or something totally different.... or its not possible at all (which is, in my oppinion, the real answer :))

Comment: You could store each number as a distance from the previous number (1-3) but do it as a 2-bit number. You could then pack 4 numbers into every byte. The downside of this is, to determine any given number in the sequence, you'd have to start at the beginning. You and add up all the distances.

Comment: Yeh.. I already pack 4 numbers into 1 byte. I was wondering, if there is a better solution to this "problem"

Comment: You might be able to eek out the half a bit that's unused and get a bit more space. But if the numeric sequence is really random, then you're unlikely to get much value from compression algorithms as they're generally based on the idea of some sort of repetetive sequence and random data usually lacks this.

Comment: The real question, I suppose is, is your data truly random? Some sort of natural phenomenon, perhaps? Or is there possibly some deep pattern to be found in it? If there's no pattern to be found, there's no compressability.

Comment: They are pretty much random... but most frequent value is 1 (about more than 80% of data), than 2 and 3. There is no "visible" pattern. Thats why I thought of using for example Neural Network to find any. Or if **original** data are plotted, they are very close to linear function (after linear regression in excel, Reliability = 0.9998)

Answer (score 0):

Since you say in the comments that you're already storing four differences per byte, you're likely to not do much better.  If the differences 0, 1, 2, and 3 were random and evenly distributed, then there would be no way to do better.

If they are not evenly distributed, then you might be able to do better with a Huffman or arithmetic code.  E.g. if 1 is more common than 0, which is more common than 2 and 3, then you could store 1 as 0, 0 as 10, 2 as 110, and 3 as 111.  Or if 0 never happens, 1 as 0, 2 and 3 as 10 and 11.  You could do better with an arithmetic code for the case you quote where 1 occurs 80% of the time.  Or a poor man's arithmetic code by coding pairs of symbols.  E.g.:

```
11 0
13 100
21 101
12 110
31 1110
22 111100
23 111101
32 111110
33 111111
```

would be a good code for 1 80%, 2 10%, 3 10%.  (That doesn't quite handle the case of an odd number of differences, but you could deal with that with just a bit at the start indicating an even or odd number, and a few more bits at the end if odd.)

There might be a better predictor than the previous value.  This would be a function of *n* previous values instead of just one previous value.  However this would be highly data dependent.  For example you could assume that the current value is likely to fall on the line made by the previous two values.  Or that it falls on the parabola made by the previous three values.  Or some other function, e.g. a sinusoid with some frequency, if the data is so biased.